# In nodemailer, How to format text email Body

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I have text body in nodemailer. I want to format text in email.

```
 var mailOptions={
        to      : data.toAddress,
        cc      : data.ccAddress,
        bcc     : data.bccAddress,
        subject : data.subject,
        text    : data.message
    }
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
        if(error){
            callback(null, error);
        }else{
            callback(response);
        }
    });
```

For eg; inculde bullet style, bold specific word.

But in documentation I am not finding specific section.

Kindly let me know if any one has any idea on this.

Answer (score 6):

You just to add html:

```
const message = {
  from: "sender@server.com",
  to: "receiver@sender.com",
  subject: "Message title",
  text: "Plaintext version of the message",
  html: "<p>HTML version of the message</p>"
};
```

- from - The email address of the sender. All email addresses can be
  plain ‘sender@server.com’ or formatted ’“Sender Name”
  sender@server.com‘, see Address object for details.
- to - Comma separated list or an array of recipients email addresses
  that will appear on the To: field.
- cc - Comma separated list or an       array of recipients email
  addresses that will appear on the Cc:       field.
- bcc - Comma separated list or an array of recipients email addresses 
  that will appear on the Bcc: field.
- subject - The subject of the email. text - The plaintext version of
  the message as an Unicode string, Buffer, Stream or an
  attachment-like object ({path: ‘/var/data/…’}).
- html - The HTML version of the message as an Unicode string, Buffer, 
  Stream or an attachment-like object ({path: ‘http://…‘}).
- attachments - An array of attachment objects (see Using attachments
  for details). Attachments can be used for embedding images as well.

Answer (score 2):

If u want to format text in email you must write this text using HTML syntax eg.

```
var message = "<p style='font-weight:bold;'> Hi. My name is John </p>";

var mailOptions={
    to      : data.toAddress,
    cc      : data.ccAddress,
    bcc     : data.bccAddress,
    subject : data.subject,
    text    : message
}
smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
    if(error){
        callback(null, error);
    }else{
        callback(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, But It came like <p style='font-weight:bold;'> Hi. My name is John </p>.

I think need to use html.

But in that case all \n remove..

Comment: You can replace '\n' with '<br/>'