# How to send newsletter form to the email in designed way but not html code from nodejs?

Tags: html, node.js, gmail, handlebars.js, html-email

I am trying to send the confirmation email to user's email. But what I noticed is that instead of UI I a getting the whole `UI html code` itself but not the design in `Gmail`.

Below is the screenshot what I am getting into my Gmail:
[image]

And this what I want in actual which is behind the code. (UI part only)
[image]

So basically I am getting the html code itself in gmail but I want the UI behind that code which is also functioning.

Comment: I am not a node.js guy but it seems you might be sending the plain text version. Change the mime type for the email to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In nodemailer, How to format text email Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37676814/in-nodemailer-how-to-format-text-email-body)